# 40-50-90 Triangle with Cosine Equation

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Triangle DEF contains right angle E. If angle D measures 40° and its adjacent side measures 7.6 units, what is the measure of side EF? Round your answer to the nearest hundredth.

So far, I have angle measures of 40, 50, and 90. Side DE is 7.6 units and the right ratio to use for this problem is cos, which is opp/adj.

The equation so far is c= E/cos40 degrees, the answer I got was c= E/0.766044443 but I have no clue where to go from there.

Comment: You are in panic mode, mixing things up: $c=E /\cos{40°}$ makes no sense, as $c$ (small lettre) does not exist, and you can't divide $E$ (a point) by a number (this can only be done with other numbers, like the length of $CE$ or the length of $DE$). Try to write your formula as strictly correct as possible and you'll see the solution unfolding. Good luck :-)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Of course, we are all here to help, but there are some things you assumed wrong: cos(x) = adj/hyp, not opp/adj. That would be the tangent function. Also, what you plugged into the formula is also wrong. See my answer for the correct answer.

Comment: Based on your posted question, and the responses that it generated, I surmise that you have an underlying obstacle.  You don't understand the concepts involved.  Trying to attack math problems in such a situation is the wrong move.  I suggest that you first carefully study the material to actually learn the concepts, and only then attack the corresponding math problems.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, we have the following where we have to find $x$:

[image]

Yes, it’s a crude drawing, but you get the point.

Here, we would use $\tan(x)$, which is opposite over adjacent:

Here we have:

$\tan(40^\circ) = \frac{x}{7.6}$

Now to solve for $x$, we multiply both sides by $7.6$:

$x = 7.6 \cdot \tan(40)$

If you had a calculator, $\tan(40) \approx 0.84$.

Hence, $x = EF \approx 6.37 \text{ or } 6.38$.

In general, you can always just use the appropriate trig function and then solve for the unknown side $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, the correct answer rounds to about 6.38.